# Discord bot yields error Error[TOKEN_INVALID] An invalid token was provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a discord bot. After all code was done, I ran `node index.js` to start the bot. It returned this error:

```
PS F:\DISCORDBOTS\Ultron> node index.js
F:\DISCORDBOTS\Ultron\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:206
    if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');
                                                   ^

Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (F:\DISCORDBOTS\Ultron\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:206:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\DISCORDBOTS\Ultron\index.js:98:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'
}
```

I am using `.env` for the Token for the bot. I even regenerated the token many times but it still returns the same error. I could use a `config.json` file but then the Token will be visible to all on repl.it. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried printing the token just before passing it to the function, and making sure it's the same as the one you got from Discord? It could be that you're failing to load it correctly or that it's overridden somewhere.

Comment: printing the token??

Comment: Yes, add a `console.log(token)` in your code and check it's correct (assuming you're running this locally and you're the only one seeing it).

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: Do you use dotenv to load variables from your `.env` file? If yes, how do you require and configure it?

Comment: Take a look at [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: sorry for being late, i was out of house. i use `config.json` for the prefix and other stuff. `.env` is just for the token and api keys which will be added later. to require i use `require('dotenv').config` and to process it i use `bot.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

Comment: and also, i noticed i  dont have the dotenv package installed in the bot dir, so i installed it and recreated the `.env` file. it still returns the same error ;-;

Answer (score 0):

We have to provide the token in string format. In client code it is written like this (if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');).So try this code.I also have the same error when i change to this code then my code running fine.

```
    const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
    require("dotenv").config();
    const client = new Client({intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });                                         
    const mySecret = process.env['TOKEN'];
     client.on("ready", () => {
     console.log(`Logged is as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    });


   client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if(msg.content === "ping"){
    msg.reply("pong");
   }
   });

   client.login(mySecret);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const mySecret = `${process.env['TOKEN']}`;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.